# check object each property value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check object's each property value if all value equal to 0 then alert. Below code is performing alert if only one property contains 0

```
var arr={a:"0", b:"1", c:"2"};
$.each(arr,function(i,val){
    if(val=="0")
    alert(0)
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually using an *Object*, not an *Array*, so loop with [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
function allEqualTo(obj, test) {
    var key;
    for (key in obj) 
        if (obj[key] !== test)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Now

```
var o = {a:"0", b:"1", c:"2"};
if (allEqualTo(o, "0"))
    alert(0);
else
    alert('foobar');
// foobar alerted
```

Comment: A clean and re-usable method using only native JS. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want it by jquery use this code:

```
var bOk = true;
$.each(arr,function(i,val){
    if (val != 0) return bOk = false;
})
if (bOk) alert(0);
```

Comment: You have two delimiters on one line, you can shorten this function a little so you have just one if you do `return bOk = false;`

Comment: Except the method you're referring to is `Array.prototype.filter()` and `arr` is actually an `Object`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Yes, that's true. I've forgot this fact